# I would like to recover an id and insert it into several src, to avoid repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, this

I want to retrieve "id" from each post to use in various places inside the post.
How can I achieve that?

```js
$("a").attr("onclick", function() {
  return "changeVideo('" + this.id + "')";
});
$("video").attr("src", function() {
  return "https://WebSite" + this.id + "-.jpg";
});
$("video").attr("src", function() {
  return "https://WebSite" + this.id + "-preview.mp4";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>first post</h2>

<div title="First Post" id="1/1/8/2/1/4/4/5c5417cfefafd-677">
  <a onclick="changeVideo('[Retrieve the id from the first post div]')">
    <div class="thumb" onclick="clicksound.playclip()" onMouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()">
      <video muted poster="retrieve the id from the first post div" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
        <source src="retrieve the id from the first post div" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<h2>second post</h2>

<div title="Second Post" id="1/1/8/2/1/4/4/5c5417cfefafd-677">
  <a onclick="changeVideo('[retrieve the id from the second post div]')">
    <div class="thumb" onclick="clicksound.playclip()" onMouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()">
      <video muted poster="retrieve the id from the second post div" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
        <source src="retrieve the id from the second post div" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: set a class for the Post div called `class="Post"` Then use `$(this).closest('.Post').attr('id')` .. OR If only the parent div has a title attribute you can use `$(this).closest('[title]').attr('id')`

Comment: Agreed. In your functions, `this` refers to the element you've selected, not the post's containing `<div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key here, is to loop through all the `.post`... And there is 3 attributes to set for each.

See comments in code.

```js
// Loop through each post
$(".post").each(function(){
  
  // Get the id
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  
  // Set the anchor's onclick
  $(this).find("a").attr("onclick","changeVideo('" + id + "');");
  
  // Set the poster and src
  $(this).find("video").attr({
    "poster":"https://WebSite" + id + "-.jpg",
    "src":"https://WebSite" + id + "-preview.mp4"
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>first post</h2>
<div class="post" title="First Post" data-id="1/1/8/2/1/4/4/5c5417cfefafd-677">
  <a onclick="">
    <div class="thumb">
      <video muted poster="" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<h2>second post</h2>
<div class="post" title="Second Post" data-id="A-DIFFERENT-ID-FOR-FUN">
  <a onclick="">
    <div class="thumb">
      <video muted poster="" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The `id` you look for is in a [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute in the `.post` element's markup. It also is the parent of the element you wish to "update"... So it's a good starting point to retreive the `id` and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the childs. An [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) loop is the best way to process them all correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your functions, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the element to which you've bound the function.
Here's a demonstration:

```js
$("video").attr("poster", function() {
  console.log("This refers to: " + this);
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video></video>
```

But it seems that you want to get the `id` attribute from the containing `<div>` for each post.

1. I suggest that you assign each post `<div>` a class of "post".
   Then you can select the desired post from within your functions by using jQuery's [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

   ```
   <div class="post" ... >
   ```
2. I recommend that you use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) like `data-id` rather than the `id` attribute,
   since the `id` attribute has its own [specific purpose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

   ```
   <div class="post" data-id="1/1/8/2/1/4/4/5c5417cfefafd-677" ... >
   ```
3. I recommend removing the `<a>` elements and binding a `click` handler directly to the `.thumb` elements. That way you simplify your HTML structure and don't need the inline `onclick=""` attributes.

Here's a working example:

```js
$("video").attr({
  'poster': function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.post').data('id');
    return "https://WebSite" + id + "-.jpg";
  },
  'src': function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.post').data('id');
    return "https://WebSite" + id + "-preview.mp4";
  }
});

$(".thumb").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).closest('.post').data('id');
  changeVideo(id);
});

function changeVideo(id) {
  console.log('Changing Video: ' + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>first post</h2>
<div class="post" title="First Post" data-id="1/1/8/2/1/4/4/5c5417cfefafd-677">
  <div class="thumb">
    <video muted poster="" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>second post</h2>
<div class="post" title="Second Post" data-id="a-different-video-id">
  <div class="thumb">
    <video muted poster="" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

That results in a structure like this:

```
<div class="post" title="First Post" data-id="1/1/8/2/1/4/4/5c5417cfefafd-677">
  <div class="thumb">
    <video muted="" poster="https://WebSite1/1/8/2/1/4/4/5c5417cfefafd-677-.jpg" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause()" src="https://WebSite1/1/8/2/1/4/4/5c5417cfefafd-677-preview.mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

And jQuery has bound a `click` handler to each `.thumb`, which will pass the appropriate `data-id` to the `changeVideo()` function.